# Pasting tcpstream input to a textbox

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, backgroundworker, streamreader

So Ive been at it for some time.

Reaching the end of the stream the program freezes till there is new input only to freeze again.

Using a thread I get the exception that I cant access the Textbox from that thread. backgroundworker just doesnt do anything.

Im really kinda lost here

my code kinda looks like this

in the class that manages the tcp stream:
    string readMessage()
    {
        return inputStream.ReadLine()
    }

in my windows form class I need to somehow keep updating the textbox with the input stream without freezing the ui

Comment: nobody will be able to help you with this as we have no idea what you are talking about. Show us some code, describe what you are trying to do, ask a question....

Comment: Assuming you are using WinForms you need to use Invoke(Delegate method) if you want to change the state of a UI component from a thread other than the thread which created the UI Component. You can use InvokeRequired to check whether you need to use Invoke()

Comment: ah damn the formatting deleted my code

Comment: so I got my method "irc.readMessage()" that returns a string from the tcp-streamreader.
I got my thread "t" in my WindowsForm class
how would I use this invoke to append the text from the readmessage method to my textbox?

Comment: It's not really enough to go on, but use something like this - Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => action())); Where the action is whatever code you are trying to change the text in the text box with.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string readMessage()
    {
        string message;
        message = inputStream.ReadLine();
        return message;
    }
```

that is what handles the tcp stream

now in my main form class it looks like this:

```
void Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        n+=1;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(n);
    }

    public void update()
    {
        Channel.AppendText(irc.readMessage());
    }
    void WORK()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Channel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => update()));
        }
    }
```

Work is the method called by the thread, while refresh is a method called by a timer that periodically sets the main thread to rest so the other thread can do it's work

that got it to run... until it reaches the end of the current stream and freezes again, until there is a new input in the stream which it quickly writes to the textbox and freezez again, which is exactly what I don't want.

edit: I managed to get it to work with the tcp.SenderTimeout, setting the timeout to a few ms and only updating the chat once a second but it still feels really unresponsive.
Is there a way to make it run smoother in the background? since Ill also have to work and respond to the input at runtime.